# Bulk update using the JSON Merge Patch Specification (RFC 7396)

Tags: json, rest, merge, patch

I am having a problem understanding how to use `JSON Merge Patch` [(RFC 7396)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7396) when dealing with bulk updates, or if it even makes sense. I can't find any specifications or examples.

**Description**

We have a `/contacts` endpoint and we implemented

- a `POST` method to create Contacts and
- a `PATCH` method to update fields on a Contact. The PATCH method is compliant with the `JSON Merge Patch` specification.

So let's say `Contact` has an `Id`, and an `Organisation`. And that we have the following 2 Contact objects

```
{
  "id" : "123",
  "organisation" : "Org1. Ltd"
}
```

and

```
{
  "id" : "456",
  "organisation" : "Org2. Ltd"
}
```

**Updating a single Contact using *JSON Merge Patch* Specification**

Now using the PATCH endpoint, I can update a Contact's Organisation this way:

```
PATCH /contacts/123
Content-Type: application/merge-patch+json

{
  "organisation" : "A better name for my Org. Ltd"
}
```

**Updating several Contacts using *JSON Patch* Specification**

I understand how to update several contacts at once using the `JSON Patch` specification ([RCF 6902](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902)), it would be something like:

```
PATCH /contacts
Content-Type: application/json-patch+json

[
   { "op": "update", "path": "/123/organisation", "value" : "A better name for my Org. Ltd" },
   { "op": "update", "path": "/456/organisation", "value" : "Acme Ltd" }
]
```

**Question: Updating several Contacts using *JSON Merge Patch* Specification**

My question is how am I supposed to write the JSON if I want to update both contacts at once using the `JSON Merge Patch` specification?

I can think of something like this

```
PATCH /contacts
Content-Type: application/merge-patch+json

[
    "123" : {
        "organization":"A better name for my Org. Ltd"
    },
    "456" : {
        "organization":"Acme Ltd"
    }
]
```

But it looks a bit ugly and non standard.

Comment: This is one of the reasons why bulk api's are said to be tricky. I am going through the same confusion of a bulk updates api. One option I am considering is to no have such an api and instead ask the client (in my case its an internal client) to call the single updates in loop. Btw, do you use java as the backend for implementing the single updates api? If so I am curious to look at the implementation. Thanks!

Comment: @AndyDufresne At the moment I just will use a simple application/json Content Type because it is a specific case I need to deal with where the same update is applied to a bunch of objects when I am given their IDs. The question is more me being curious. Regarding the single update, I am using Java in the backend but the code is quite ugly because I had to adapt legacy code for it. Basically I fetch the object to update from the database, update its fields, validate it and then save it back, nothing fancy.